# How can I convert a cell to matrices by loop using with cell2mat in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have a cell `A(361,1)` which contains `361 x 3D` matrices. The first and second dimensions of matrices are same but the length of third dimension varies.

So the cell A looks like:

```
A={(464x201x31);(464x201x28);(464x201x31);(464x201x30)....}
```

I would like to get back the matrices from this cell by loop. I tried the following solution:

```
for i=1:361;
M(i)=cell2mat(A(i));
end
```

But I got the following error:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: What dimensions do you want for your final matrices?

Comment: Do you want to concatenate all of the 3D matrices together? It's a bit unclear on what you want.

Comment: If you are trying to get a 4 dimensional matrix as output, the size of each 3D matrix must be same.. but its different in your case. thats the reason why you got the error. Instead you could `cat` them to single 3D matrix as rayryeng suggests.

Comment: Check out the edit if that is what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** If you want to **access each 3D array** separately from the cell array, you could always use `A{i}` to get each 3D matrix.

Example:

```
%// Here i have taken example cell array of 1D matrix 
%// but it holds good for any dimensions

A = {[1,2,3], [1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6]};

>> A{1}

ans =

 1     2     3
```

**2.** Instead, if you want to **concatenate** all those 3D matrices **into a single three dimensional matrix**, here is one approach

```
out = cell2mat(permute(A,[1 3 2]));  %// assuming A is 1x361 from your example
```

or

```
out = cell2mat(permute(A,[3 2 1]));  %// assuming A is 361x1
```

**3.** Instead if you wanna **NaN pad** them **to obtain 4D matrix**,

```
maxSize = max(cellfun(@(x) size(x,3),A));   
f = @(x) cat(3, x, nan(size(x,1),size(x,2),maxSize-size(x,3)));  
out = cellfun(f,A,'UniformOutput',false); 
out = cat(4,out{:});
```

Sample run:

```
>> A

A = 

[3x4x2 double]    [3x4x3 double]    [3x4x4 double]

>> size(out)

ans =

 3     4     4     3 
%// note the first 3 size. It took the max size of the 3D matrices. i.e 3x4x4
%// Size of 4th dimension is equal to the no. of 3D matrices
```

You could access each 3D matrix by `out(:,:,:,i)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would like to get 361 piece 3D matrices. Could you suggest an appropriate loop?

Comment: @Beata, that would be a 4D matrix.. but your 3rd dimensions are not consistent.. eg. 31, 28, 31, 30 etc.. Instead you could NaN pad them to make it consistent & obtain them.. are you sure you wanna do that?

Comment: @Beata people will keep misinterpreting what you want if you don't clarify your original post. We asked at least three questions and you haven't replied to any. You can't expect us to give you the right answer if we can't understand what you want.

Comment: Btw +1 for you Santhan for trying to answer this unclear question.

Comment: @rayryeng, Thanks. Sometimes by answering I learn something :)

Comment: Sorry for my delay! I accepted Santhan Salai suggestion. I produced 4D matrices using NaN pad. Thank you again for your help!